# Isn't this CONSTRAINT just adding extra steps?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently following a tutorial, and I'm not a stranger to SQL, but if I want to make NOT NULL or PRIMARY KEY constraints I usually would do something like

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    CustNo VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    CustName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    Address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    Internal CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
    Contact VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL, 
    Phone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    City VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    Zip VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

But in this tutorial it does this instead for the "answer key" and it also only does this for PostgreSQL but not for Oracle or MySql examples:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    CustNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT CustNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
    CustName VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT CustNameNotNull NOT NULL, 
    Address VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT AddressNotNull NOT NULL, 
    Internal CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT InternalNotNull NOT NULL, 
    Contact VARCHAR(35) CONSTRAINT ContractNotNull NOT NULL, 
    Phone VARCHAR(11) CONSTRAINT CPhoneNotNull NOT NULL, 
    City VARCHAR(30) CONSTRAINT CityNotNull NOT NULL,
    State VARCHAR(2) CONSTRAINT StateNotNull NOT NULL, 
    Zip VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT zipNotNull NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT PK_CUSTOMER PRIMARY KEY (CustNo) 
);
```

Is there a real advantage to doing it their way?

Comment: This is just different platforms doing things different ways.

Comment: I figured as much

Comment: Syntactic sugar in case you want to refer to the constraint by name.

Comment: For primary keys, you don't need to define them as not null. They are not null as per definition of PK

Comment: Named constrains will perhaps give better error messages?

Answer (score 2):

There is really no difference. Except for the time your primary key is not on a single column. In this case you have to use second format.